# date formatting string in vb mvc

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I format my vb.net mvc date to a shortdate in my view

```
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.DateCreated)%>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format(date, "MM/dd/YYYY")

I don't know what modelItem is, but i think you are looking to do this

```
<td>
    <%: HTML.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem), Format(currentItem.DateCreated, "MM/dd/YYYY")) %>
</td>
```

Not sure if thats right, i don't really know what Html.DisplayFor actually does. I've never ran into that before. But the Format(yourdate, shortdateformat) will definitely work

Comment: I'm getting the following error: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: Would you mind updating your original post with what modelItem does? Also, is currentItem.DateCreated just the date you want to format? 
If so you can probably get away with a <%= currentItem.DateCreated.Tostring("MM/dd/YYYY") %>